# Updated iOS binary not updating MainView NIB

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uibutton, nib

So I'm about to update my app and I have ran into a problem.  On my main screen I have a series of UIButtons that lead to different views.  I created the UIButtons using Interface Builder.

In my latest update, I want to disable the buttons until the appropriate data is downloaded from the server.  For some strange reason, any changes I make to the NIB in Interface Builder are not working.  For example, I disable a button in IB, but it will still be active when I Build & Run.  It's like it's using the NIB from the previous version still.  I've tried deleting buttons from the NIB, but they still show up in the simulator or device.  The only way I have found to fix it, although not ideal, is to delete the entire app of the device or simulator and install a fresh copy.  But my users are probably not going to do that.  They'll simply download the update from the App Store.

I've also tried Cleaning before Running, that didn't work either.

Any thoughts???  Is this an Interface Builder bug??

**EDIT:** I suppose I could rename the nib and force the update to load the new version of itself.

**UPDATE:**  Renaming the Main NIB file worked forcing the device/simulator to update the file.  I truly think this is a bug somewhere.  My code may be sloppy at times, but I know how to enable/disable buttons.

Comment: You must be altering it's state in code then.  add the line [self.button setEnabled:NO]; and see if that helps.

Comment: I ran into this problem after creating a new app version with localized nib files. When upgrading, both the original and localized versions were there, and the app defaulted to the original. Not sure if that's your issue, but you don't have to worry about customers having problems. This is only an issue when installing through Xcode. Those old nibs will be wiped when upgrading via the App Store.

Comment: @RobBajorek I believe that is the issue.  Thanks for the info!!

Comment: The post is too old and I do not know if you've found an answer to your question, though I'm willing to share my experience because I've also faced such problem a few times. In iOS prior to version 6.0, resource names are case-insensitive. For ex. `NSArray *items = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NIBName" owner:nil options:nil]; `and `NSArray *items = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"nibName" owner:nil options:nil];` produce different results in iOS 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't your fault. This is a deficiency in how Xcode (more than a year after the question above was asked) installs resources in an app folder, either to the simulator or a device, prior to running. It copies new or changed resources (which is great, because it shortens install time) but it does *not* delete obsolete ones. This behavior bit me when I was moving away from using .xib files in some of my view controllers - I actually deleted them from the project, but the view controllers kept loading them anyway, which was mystifying and disturbing until I figured out what was going on.

Deleting the app from the simulator or device prior to installing will, perforce, remove the old resources as well, and the next install will have only the resources specified in your build.

I'm still working on a solution; if I think of it, I'll update this answer if and when I come up with something.

This problem does *not* occur when installing from the App Store or from an .ipa file - it appears that this install process does a clean reinstall of resources.